# Why can a Faraday pail not be cumulatively charged from a battery?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, voltage, batteries

First consider a commonly performed [Faraday ice pail experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday's_ice_pail_experiment) and my question will naturally follow:

If a charged object is allowed to touch the inside of a Faraday Pail, the charge will be transferred to the outside of the pail. The object can be removed and recharged, and inserted into the pail again to transfer additional charge to the pail.  This can be repeated over and over whereby the outside of the pail gains more and more charge thereby reaching significantly high voltages.

So my question is:

Intuitively, I would think that connecting one pole of a battery to the inside of a Faraday Pail and the other pole to Earth would allow the battery to transfer its charge continuously into the Pail, resulting in in a very high voltage on the outside of the pail (and a rather significant drain on the battery).

However... I tried that and it doesn't work.  Can someone explain why this doesn't work?  Why doesn't a wired battery cause the same effect as a single charged object?

I find it even more perplexing that a Van De Graff Generator employs a wire connection between the inside of the Faraday Pail and the belt where charge is picked up.  Obviously, the wire connection is not an obstacle in transferring the charge.  So why doesn't the battery work for charging the pail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get something for nothing.
As the charge on the ice pail and the Van de Graaff dome is increased so their potentials relative to earth is also increased.

This means that adding the next amount of charge will require more work to be done by the external force moving a certain amount of charge so a greater external force needs to be applied.
When doing the experiment with the ice pail I do not think that this extra force is noticeable.
However as a small Van de Graaff charges up the speed of the motor driving the belt decreases showing that the motor is doing more work.

With the battery the amount of work which can be done in moving unit charge is fixed.
It is the emf of the battery and so once the ice pail reaches that potential no extra charge can be added to the ice pail.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that your claim about the Van de Graaff motor being further loaded as the dome gains charge is untrue.  The inside of the dome remains neutral at all times, allowing it to accept more and more charge.  Because the inside is always neutral, the effect and load on the belt and combs is always the same regardless of the exterior charge on the dome.

Comment: @Jim As the belt goes up the charge on it sees the outside of the dome which has the same type of charge. Work needs to be done to move the charge on the belt up.  The VdG generator I have access to have small electric motors moving the belt.  As the dome charges up there is a noticeable change in the pitch of the motor indicating that the motor is slowing down.

Answer (score 1):

The battery has a fixed EMF, i.e. voltage $V$. When you connect one pole to earth and the other to earth, you apply a voltage $V$ to the pail capacitance $C$ with respect to earth and a charge $Q=C·V$ will be transferred to the pail. Then the current stops because the voltage of the pail versus earth is the same as the battery voltage. You could, however, repeatedly charge a smaller conducting sphere capacitance with the battery and transfer its charge after disconnection from the battery to the pail and thus charge the pail to a much higher charge and voltage.

Comment: I understand that this is the true behavior that is observed.  But I'm looking for an answer that better explains what's happening with the charge behavior.  With the traditional Faraday Pail experiment, the inside of the pail always stays neutral, which is the reason more charge can always be accepted by the inside of the pail.  I don't understand why the same behavior doesn't occur with a battery hooked up.

Comment: @Jim - It is, in the end, an energy problem. When you charge the pail, which has the potential $V_p=Q_p/C$, by transporting an additional charge $\Delta Q$ mechanically (from earth) to its interior, you have to perform mechanical work $W=\Delta Q V_p$ to lift the charge to the pail potential. With the battery, you can only provide charge at a fixed potential $V$. Thus, if the pail potential $V_p$ is already at the battery voltage $V$ no more charge can be transferred to the pail by the battery because this would raise the pail potential $V_p$ above the battery voltage $V$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment.  Both you and Farcher were very helpful.  I had a tough time deciding which answer to accept since they were both acceptable.  I upvoted everything. :)